# Access denied when trying to create new X509Store, using Rider on a Mac

Tags: c#, macos, rider

I am trying to execute the following code

```
X509Store someStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
```

Getting this error

```
  {System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store}
    Certificates: {System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection}
    IsOpen: false
    Location: CurrentUser
    Name: "Root"
    StoreHandle: Exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' was thrown
    _storePal: null
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Nothing wrong with that line of code per se.  Can you give more detail of your code and the exception?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.